# Horizontal list of divs with scroll not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a list of boxes that moves horizontally, but at the end of the first line it goes for the second line.

```css
.container {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.box {
    max-width: 98%;
    min-width: 150px;
    background-color: #F4D989;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: white-space: nowrap; is intended for text only / inline elements, which is why it's not working for you on elements. You should create an overflowing slider instead.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `float` from `.box`, and add `display: inline-block;`, as `white-space` only works on inline level elements.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine. Put your boxes in a div class other than the main container. Try the below code:

```css
.box-wrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.box {
    max-width: 98%;
    min-width: 150px;
    background-color: #F4D989;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-wrap">
    <div class="box" style="width: 100px;height:100px;background-color: red;"></div>
    <div class="box" style="width: 100px;height:100px;background-color: black;"></div>
    <div class="box" style="width: 100px;height:100px;background-color: red;"></div>
</div>
```

Below is a screenshot of how it works, I used different colors to make each box distinct.
[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3LNM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.container{
    white-space:nowrap;
    display: inline-flex
    overflow-x:auto;
}
```